# Calling javascript file after AJAX event without function

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm editing a theme to use a different 'lightbox' effect other than PrettyPhoto, the one it came with.  I rewrote everything fine except that it has a AJAX filter that toggles 'categories', which then requires the Lightbox scripts to reload after the event occurs.  I am not familiar enough with AJAX to write this, but I did identify where this event is happening and even what the original developer had in place for the PrettyPhoto function to 'reload' after the AJAX event.  His function is as follows :

```
$list.quicksand($sorted_data, $preferences, function () {
                            over();
                            hover_opacity();
                            prettyPhoto();

                    });
```

Can I write something there in place of `prettyPhoto()` to call outside javascript files?  Do I need to write a function for the new Lightbox effect and call it there or can I get away with just calling the same `.js` files like I do in the header?

I hope that makes sense.  My knowledge on AJAX is quite limited.  Many thanks SO.